# Order by a field in custom model defined in belongs to many association. Also select few fields

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hapi.js

### What you are doing?

I have a user model and a cards model. They are associated with each other by custom table 'favouriteCards'. Now I want to select all the cards `favourited` by a user and order them by `createdAt` field.

```
models.user.belongsToMany(models.card, { 
     through: 'favouriteCards' 
});

models.card.belongsToMany(models.user, {
    through: 'favouriteCards',
    scope: {
        status: 'active'
    }
});
```

I am writing this code to get all the cards a user has:-

```
this.database.user.findById(userId).then((user: any) => {
user.getCards({
    attributes: ['id', 'storyId', 'mediaUri', 'mediaType', 'externalLink']
})
    .then((cards: Array<any>) => {
        if (cards.length) {
            return Promise.resolve(cards);
        } else {
            throw 'No favourite cards';
        }
    }).then((cards: Array<any>) => {
        return reply({
            "cards": cards
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return reply(Boom.notFound("User doesn't have any favourite card"));
    });
});
```

### What is actually happening?

Now, in the output, I get a key `favouriteCards`. I don't want this key in the output. Also, I want to filter my results based on the `createdAt` column of `favouriteCards`.

*Output JSON*

```
"cards": [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "storyId": 3,
       "mediaUri": "http://localhost/api/docs#!/admin/postStory",
       "mediaType": "image",
       "favouriteCards": {
          "createdAt": "2017-08-05T11:45:29.000Z",
           "updatedAt": "2017-08-05T11:45:29.000Z",
           "cardId": 1,
           "userId": 1
        }
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try include option with an empty array

e.g

```
this.database.user.findById(userId).then((user: any) => {
user.getCards({
    attributes: ['id', 'storyId', 'mediaUri', 'mediaType', 'externalLink'],
    include: []
})
    .then((cards: Array<any>) => {
        if (cards.length) {
            return Promise.resolve(cards);
        } else {
            throw 'No favourite cards';
        }
    }).then((cards: Array<any>) => {
        return reply({
            "cards": cards
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return reply(Boom.notFound("User doesn't have any favourite card"));
    });
});
```